# How to use fork in order to run NPM scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fork, child-process

I have an NPM start script that works well from the CLI.
I'm trying to use `fork()` so it will run a child process, then that child process will return some data to the parent. And then use a node-cron scheduler to run it daily.

It works when i use a simple exec like this

**parent.js**

```
const cp = require('child_process');
cp.exec("npm run start argument1 argument2", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
     console.log('exec',stdout)
});
```

**child.js**

```
let data = someCode()
process.stdout.write("data:" + JSON.stringify(data))
```

But then i cannot get the data back to the parent, so i tried this which does not work:

**parent.js**

```
const cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork("npm run start argument1 argument2", [], { silent: true });

child.on("message", (data) =>{
    console.log('data',data)
})
```

**child.js**

```
let data = someCode()
process.stdout.write("data:" + JSON.stringify(data))
process.send(res)
```

It's doesn't even run the script, ut it's also not returning any error.

**Edit**:
Maybe it's related to the `babel-node` ? 
Here is how the package.json looks:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node index.js --",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "memory-cache": "^0.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "puppeteer": "2.0.0",
    "puppeteer-firefox": "^0.5.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Fork](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) should point to a file, and you don't need `{silent:true}`, let the forked process inherit the parents stdio.

Check out the **demo** below:

**parent.js**

```
const {fork} = require('child_process');
var child = fork("./child.js", ['argument1','argument2']);

// send data to child.js
child.send({ hello: 'world' });

// receive data from child.js
child.on("message", (fromChild) =>{
    console.log('Incoming data from child.js', fromChild)
});
```

**child.js**

```
const someCode = ()=> [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let data = someCode();

// send data to parent.js
process.send({data, custom_arguments: process.argv.slice(2)});

// receive data from parent.js
process.on('message', (fromParent) => {

    console.log('Incoming data from parent.js:', fromParent);

});
```

Comment: Still not working. May it got something to do with babel-node ? have added the package.json in the original post.

Comment: My answer works fine. Update your post with the current code you're expecting to work, and the nodejs version

Comment: It doesn't run the script in this case. Please look at the cp.exec, that version run the script well.